# error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<Pet*>::vector(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

Hi I need help fixing this error for C++.
I'm trying to create a function that returns a vector containing pet objects.
I tried using pushback, still won't compile.
I have a bunch of other classes(cat,dog, fish etc..) that also inherits the base pet class.

Here is a snip it of my function.

```
std::vector<Pet*> make_pets() {

    //why doesn't this work?
std::vector<Pet*> newVector {Cat(), Dog()};
   return newVector;
//newVector.push_back(c);


}
```

Comment: `Cat()` is a `Pet`, not a `Pet*`. You're probably aiming for `new Cat()`, but you are much better off changing the `vector` to `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Pet>` and `Cat()` to `std::make_unique<Cat>()`. The `unique_ptr` will safely take care of the memory management for you.

Comment: Hello, so i did what you said and i'm getting an error when i try to return my newVector - error: could not convert 'newVector' from 'std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Pet> >' to 'std::vector<Pet*>'
code here  : std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Pet>> newVector;
newVector.push_back(std::make_unique<Cat> ()); return newVector;

Comment: The types must remain the same throughout. If you return a ``std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Pet>>`, the variable receiving it needs to be a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Pet>>`

Answer (score 3):

The error in OPs code:

```
std::vector<Pet*> newVector {Cat(), Dog()};
```

`Cat()` creates a temporary instance of `Cat`. The type is `Cat` (or `Cat&`).
The element type of `std::vector<Pet*>` is `Pet*` which isn't compatible. Applying the address operator (`&Cat()`) would make things worse. Although the type would match now (`Cat*` can be assigned to `Pet*` if `Cat` is derived from `Pet`) , `Cat()` creates a *temporary* instance. It doesn't provide sufficient life-time because it's auto-destroyed at end of expression, which would leave a dangling pointer in the `std::vector`.

To fix this, `new` can be used:

```
std::vector<Pet*> newVector {new Cat(), new Dog()};
```

MCVE on coliru:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct Pet {
  virtual ~Pet() = default;
  virtual const char* what() const = 0;
};

struct Cat: public Pet {
  virtual const char* what() const override { return "cat"; }
};

struct Dog: public Pet {
  virtual const char* what() const override { return "dog"; }
};

std::vector<Pet*> make_pets()
{
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Pet>> vec{ new Cat(), new Dog() };
  return vec;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Pet>> pets = make_pets();
  std::cout << "Pets:\n";
  for (const Pet *pPet : pets) std::cout << pPet->what() << '\n';
  for (const Pet *pPet : pets) delete pPet;
}
```

Output:

```
Pets:
cat
dog
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08b094abe5cbb0f6)

Creating instances with `new` causes that these instances have to be destroyed explicitly with `delete`. Just clearing the `std::vector<Pet*>` `pets` instead, would leave the instances undeleted and lost – a memory leak.

---

The usage of [**std::unique_ptr**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) (as recommended by [@user4581301](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58926355/error-no-matching-function-for-call-to-stdvectorpetvectorbrace-enclos#comment104113700_58926355)) is a bit tricky. Because an instance of `std::unique_ptr` is the one and only which owns / holds the pointee, it may not be copied or assigned but just moved. After some fiddling, I got an mcve on coliru:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct Pet {
  virtual ~Pet() = default;
  virtual const char* what() const = 0;
};

struct Cat: public Pet {
  virtual const char* what() const override { return "cat"; }
};

struct Dog: public Pet {
  virtual const char* what() const override { return "dog"; }
};

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Pet>> make_pets()
{
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Pet>> vec;
  vec.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Cat>());
  vec.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Dog>());
  return vec;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Pet>> pets = make_pets();
  std::cout << "Pets:\n";
  for (const std::unique_ptr<Pet> &pPet : pets) std::cout << pPet->what() << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
Pets:
cat
dog
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11a8720dfaebfc10)

Destruction of `Pet` instances is not an issue in this case. The `std::unique_ptr<Pet>` grants that pointee is deleted as soon as the pointer itself is deleted.